# Getting image deprecated warning launching Deep Learning VM

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning

I'm getting the following warning when trying to launch Google's Deep Learning VM for the first time:

```
tensorflow has resource level warnings
tensorflow-1-vm: The resource 'projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/tf2-2-1-cpu-20200128' is deprecated. A suggested replacement is 'projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/tf2-2-1-cpu-20200227'
```

I'm just using the GCP cloud launcher UI, so I'm surprised this is happening. Anyone know why and what is the solution?

Comment: This is an issue that has already been reported and is under internal investigation. You can find the public associated issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/155949892